# Docusign deleted template information is available long after the template is emptied out of delete bucket

Tags: docusignapi

With the REST api, I checked on two different templates, one that was deleted awhile back ( a few months ago ) and one that's still being used. The one currently in use has a folderUri": "/templates/". The one that was deleted long ago has folderUri": "/folders/". So, if a template gets used in an envelope that gets sent out, even if the template gets deleted later, that info is still in the system? Deleting the template means you can't use it anymore, but it's info is still retained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- An envelope can be created using one or multiple templates.
- If you delete the template from the account, it cannot be used to create new envelopes. Any envelopes created previously using that template are not impacted in any way.